# Transistor cross reference equivalent book

Tags: transistors, books

Some shopkeepers have a book where they read cross-reference for the transistor, it's a very handy book. I am trying to search for a PDF of that version or want to order but am not able to find it anywhere, can anyone help me with this?

Something looks like this
[image]

Comment: A physical cross reference book which claims to be "Up to Date"? Not very likely in 2022...

Answer (score 1):

the Internet is [archived also with books](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_alliedElecAlliedElectronicsCatalog_49772239/page/n2/mode/1up?q=transistor%20%22cross-ref%22)

Answer (score 0):

Years back I used BAMA (Boat Anchor Manual Archive), they have tons of manuals for electronic test gear and ham radio plus a few others. It was originally Vacuum Tube devices which has expanded dramatically over the years. This link gives a long list of sources. "https://www.virhistory.com/ham/rrab/manuals.htm". It has a link to send messages to Nick...